# Laravel project hosted in Cpanel gives HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: laravel, hosting, http-error

I created laravel 5.2 project and it works perfect in localhost..
Now when I uploaded to cpanel and tried to access through internet it gives me these errors.

access url : "http://orderproject.sutchelinks.com/public/"

> error :
>
> The orderproject.sutchelinks.com page isn’t working
>           orderproject.sutchelinks.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>           HTTP ERROR 500

what could be the reason??

Comment: Most of the time, it occurs because of the incorrect file permission. please check whether the file permission has been set correctly or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess`, add the following lines and put the file in your root folder. I see that you've got it working but you're not supposed to have the `*/public` at the end.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

Try it, I got my Laravel application working with this.